# How to convert JavaScript Date into PostgreSQL Time (no timezone)?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I use [knex](http://knexjs.org/) with [PosgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/). I have a table with a [Time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html) column.

After trying to insert data in the table, `knex` throws an error with the following message:

`...invalid input syntax for type time: \"2021-07-21T14:40:00.000+03:00\..."`

Code example

```js
await knex('table_name')
 .insert({ id: 1, time: new Date() })
```

What is a correct way to preserve JavaScript Date object as a PosgreSQL Time? Should I use 3rd party libs? Or it can be done using knex only?

Comment: Is the column of type `time` or `timestamp`? A `time` column cannot accept a date.

Comment: @Pointy, the column has type `time`

Comment: Well `time` column is about a time-of-day value, not a time on a particular date. I always use `timestamp without time zone` for Postgresql time-and-date values.

Comment: I use `time` type to save the duration of the break during the working day. It means I have a date  (without time) in a separate column of table A and a list of possible breaks (start_time: Time, end_time: Time) in table B.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by manually converting the JavaScript Date object into one of the supported formats of the PostgreSQL.

The [`8.5.1.1. Dates`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html) and [`8.5.1.2. Times`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html) chapters have a full list of supported types.

My solution was to use [`date-fns/format`](https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/format) (e.g. `format(new Date(), 'HH:mm') // 14:00`)

P.S. I'm not sure if this approach is right but it works.